# How can I show mouseover on y-axis (Not on bars), sometimes my labels are too long (I have already shorten it) and there is no data record

Tags: chart.js

I have created a graph with y-axis as project names, my project name is too long so I have already shorted it by using a callback method. My issues is I want to show it once you mouseover on y-axis so sometimes there are no records and it just shows 0 (so no tooltip is shown once you mouseover it).[image]

afterEvent: (chart, event, opts) => { }, I have already got the label value I want to show it only when it is at that specific location

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.